# What is causing the webpage to be redirected to https in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to find out how https is required on this project that has already been built.They would like me to disable https being required on all of the home pages, but everywhere else require https. As it stands right nw the website will automatically redirect to https no matter what page. The problem: I'm not sure where in this large project that is being required.  Here is what I have looked for so far:

-I looked for a SecurePages package by pressing ctrl-shift-f and searching for 
SecurePages.
 -I did this for SecureWeb and SecuritySwitch as well, but nothing showed up. 
 -I checked https to see if there was an absolute path defined in the website.  There was not. 
 -I looked in web.config and global.asax for any settings that could be causing it, but nothing looked remotely close to https.

UPDATE
After doing so digging around I've found that RequireHttpsAttribute is a filter being added inside of Filter.Config.  Is there a way to undo that filter just for a handful of webpages. There are several pages that need to be required and would be more reasonable to do it that way.

Comment: Start Point Hint: In the IIS manager (not your application config file) go to the Site and right click to the bindings menu.  See if Only HTTPS is listed and not http.  It is also on the right under Actions-Edit Site- Bindings...   This may be what is driving the behavior.  If you change this then you have to go to each sub directory and require Https and possibly other authentication and authorization settings. When you do this change you are reversing every assumption every production deployment made about security to your site.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to compromise your users security by not requiring 100% HTTPS? I cannot think of a reason to allow HTTP to your homepage.